# Web Forms Model Binding: How to omit binding for not visible control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls, model-binding

I am using the new Model Binding feature for WebForms, with .NET Framework Version 4.5.1. **What I hope to achieve is, to exclude *some* of the two-way bindings, based on some condtions.**

I very much like the (hopefully now famous) [blog post series, by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-vnext-series). I implement an editing page using the approach number two from [Web Forms Model Binding Part 3: Updating and Validation (ASP.NET 4.5 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/web-forms-model-binding-part-3-updating-and-validation-asp-net-4-5-series)

Here's what I have: (simplified, in ElementEdit.aspx):

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormViewElement" RenderOuterTable="false" DefaultMode="Edit" DataKeyNames="ElementId"
    ItemType="Business.Entities.Element"
    SelectMethod="GetElement"
    UpdateMethod="UpdateElement">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonSpeichern">
            <fieldset>
                /*some databound controls*/
                <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible="<%# !Item.CurrentElementData.SomeCondition() %>">
                    /*more databound controls*/
                </asp:Panel>
                /*the submit button ("ButtonSpeichern")*/
            </fieldset>
        </asp:Panel>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

As you see, there is a condition for the visibility on the wrapped inner panel with "more databound controls". These should bind only, when the conditioni is true, and they are visible. Otherwise they should not bind and not change the values.

The update works like in Scott's post (simplified, in xxPage.cs), which is a generic base class of Type Element:

```
protected virtual bool UpdateEntity(int id) {
    T existing = UseCase.GetItem(id); //gets the original element    

    TryUpdateModel(existing); //SHOULD NOT update the invisible databound controls, but does

    ValidateExistingEntity(existing);    
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        UseCase.Update(existing);
        return true;
    }
    ShowErrors(ModelState);
    return false;
}
```

Here, after the call to `TryUpdateModel()`, the invisible controls have updated the model, which is what I wanted to avoid.

**How to dynamically omit data binding for some elements, based on a condition, even though setting them invisible does not help?**

**UPDATE:**
I now have create a workaround, which solves the problem for me today: I simply have created two .aspx pages with their respective code behind. Depending on which fields the user should successfully edit, I call the appropriate page in the first place.

**This, however, does not solve the underlying problem, which is conditional databinding.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more an algorithm than a coded solution.

I like to use a separate class say MyData.cs to manage my data updates and pass UI elements through the 
methods of this class.
I'm like stored procedures, but you can create queries within your project.

If there is variation between which controls are visible and not, I'd recommend:

```
MyBindingMethod(array[] of the controls){
    // Loop through array updating data.
    // Or loop through array and call a second method to update the data.
}
```

Dynamically you can check the visibility of controls and then add them to the array or not to 
pass to the binding method.

If the controls that switch visibility are constant you can use two separate methods, 
to selectively update:

```
MyBindingMethodAll(){
    // Update all controls.

}

MyBindingMethodVisible(){
    // Update controls that remain visible.

}
```

Then call the methods from the MyData.cs from your aspx.cs. The trick is to maintain control of your data binding within your C# and you can determine exactly what is updated, where and when.

I am happy to provide a more detailed working example, if you are able to provide more code.

---

**Edit Update to assist in clarifying solution**

By using a separate class to manage data binding, the display element can be passed to a method of this separate class. *I've used stored procedures.*

class ManageData

```
public static void SelectAllSomething(DropDownList list)
    {
        // Clear any previously bound items.
        list.Items.Clear(); 
        // SqlConnection.
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        // Create new command and parameterise.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProcedure";

        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            // Open connection and bind data to GUI.
            con.Open();

            list.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            list.DataTextField = "Name";
            list.DataValueField = "ID";
            list.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

From you aspx.cs call the method from ManageData class.

```
ManageData.SelectAllCat(MyDropDownList);
```

Using this same principal.
Without seeing your layout I can only give you a concept example.

- if you have TextBoxes you want to control.

TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, .../

```
public static void AddText(List<TextBox> MyTextBoxes)
{
    for(int i=0; i<MyTextBoxes.Count();i++){
        MyTextBoxes.[i].Text = // What means you are using.
    }

}
```

From the aspx.cs

```
public List<TextBox> FindVisibleTextBoxes(){

    List<TextBox> MyTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
    if(TextBox1.Visible== true){
        MyTextBoxes.Add(TextBox1);
    }

    return MyTextBoxes;

}
```

Pass textbox list into method from ManageData.

This can better modularised, according to your needs and you can pass more than one List [or a List of Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass through a hetergenous mix of controls.

This is just one concept, there are many ways to go about things. I hope you find this useful to develop more ways to solve your dilemma.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be really dynamic. It looks quite involved though and takes away the simplicity and beauty of the new model binding. I hope to find some simpler solution. But, I have implemented a workaround now, see the update.

Comment: Please leave it. I'll eventually accept it. Can you provide a link about the Binding Method that receives an array of controls to specifically handle? I did a quick search on google, but found nothing further so far.